# SVG images being blurry on android browser when input tag before

Tags: android, svg, blurry

I saw a lot of probleme here about blurry svg on chrome, but my probleme is the opposite.

My svg are fine on desktop browser : safari, ffx, chrome.
and on iphone too.

but it's getting really blurry when I run my svg on the android browser of my galaxy note 2.
So I installed chrome on that device, and then the svg was good.

I tried whithout resizing in css, in background image and inside html with calling in the tag image. 
same results.

native browser android

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=923875browserandroid.png

chrome browser on android

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=266178chromeandroid.png

Comment: You may should add screenshots

Comment: Ok so I found the issue.In fact, when I insert an input tag before svg, then all the following svg get blurry. I don't know why and how to solve it. I just foud one person having the same issue here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-33189?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

Comment: Which version of Android is running on your Note 2?

Comment: my version is android 4.3